# Calculate the weight that a hot air balloon can carry

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, buoyancy, lift

Given a hot air balloon of radius 10 meters and negligible mass, calculate the maximum weight it can carry if the density of outside air is 1.2 $\frac{kg}{m^3}$ and the density of inside air is 0.9 $\frac{kg}{m^3}$.

Edit:
My attempt:
Since the maximum weight the balloon can carry is determined by the relation : 
$Q=mg$
I somehow need to set bouyancy force equal to $Q$.
Is this correct and if not, how to do it correctly?

Comment: Also have a look at this meta post http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5886/lets-not-have-posts-look-like-revision-histories and this http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange/715#715

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be solved using the Buoyancy force equation: $ F = \rho V g  $
Where F is the Buoyancy force, $\rho$ is the density difference, $ V$ is the displaced volume and $g$ is the local gravitational constant (normally assumed to be equal to $9.81$)

From your question: $ V = \frac4 3\pi r^3 = \frac4 3 (3.1416)(10)^3 = 4188.8 \space m^3 $
and $\rho = 1.2-0.9 =0.3 \frac{kg} {m^3} $

Using Newton's third law; we found that the maximum weight it could carry equals to the lifting force of the balloon. (Just for reference; the weight equals: $F_{max} =m_{max}g$.)
Therefore; 
$$
F_{max}=\rho V g \\
F_{max} =0.3\times4188.8\times9.81\\
F_{max} =12327\space N
$$
Therefore, the maximum weight it could carry is $12000\space N$ (rounded taking into account of the significant digits).